# TFS Release Step Create Task

Tags: tfs

I'm converting our XAML build process to vNEXT build for our on-premise TFS 2017. One step I like to automate is the create a work item task for a specific user to execute after the release has been done. Is there a built in way to do this? I have a PowerShell script but I'd prefer not to use it if there is already a better way

Answer (score 0):

No, there is still no out-of-the-box feature for this. Either using the REST api or the Client Object model in a powershell script just like you have done will do the trick.

You could also take a look at this similar question: [How to have TFS automatically add certain tasks to new work items?](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/293880/how-to-have-tfs-automatically-add-certain-tasks-to-new-work-items/293882#293882), *jessehouwing* has provided a great answer.

> Another way is using TFS Aggregator- a serverside pugin for TFS 2013
>   (update 2 and later) which has the ability to create new work items
>   **based on rules**. An example task can be found here:
>
> https://github.com/tfsaggregator/tfsaggregator/wiki/Auto-Create-Children

---

Update

After go through the extension in VSTS marketplace (https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/) , there is also no existing  task could do this. You may still use your powershell script or [write your own extension](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/integrate/extensions/overview).

Comment: Thanks, I don't think TFS Aggregator will work or I don't undertsand how it would connect. This would need to be a release step . It would be able to be trihered by anything in an existing workitem

Comment: @greektreat There is no out-of-the-box for your requirement. After go through the extension in VS marketplace https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/ , there is also no existing  task could do this. You may still use your powershell script or write your  own extension.